# How to optimize Redis connection pool in Spring Boot to improve the performance

Tags: spring, performance, spring-boot, redis, spring-data-redis

My application is using Spring Boot 2.2.5-RELEASE.

Application is reading and writing to the Redis single instance by using Spring Data Redis.
Application is using lettuce driver (default Spring Data Redis) with default spring pooling configurations.

```
//default-config values
spring.redis.lettuce.pool.max-active=8
spring.redis.lettuce.pool.max-idle=8
spring.redis.lettuce.pool.max-wait=-1ms
spring.redis.lettuce.pool.min-idle=0
```

How do I optimize the pool values to improve the performance of Redis.
Or any suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

Not an exact answer you might be looking for. But wanted to add this for someone who is landing on this page.

Spring Data Redis seems to be very slow by default. I switched to ***[Redisson](https://github.com/redisson/redisson)*** which provides better abstraction and performance compared to Spring Data.

Comment: I second this ! With a timeout of 50ms (I use Redis as cache so it should be pretty fast) and using Lettuce, ~10% of all queries are timing out. However, it's not the case with Redisson. I'm not sure what they do differently but it works well !